# Hello world from device+PYCUDA

Tags: printf, pycuda

I am starting to learn PyCUDA on Google Colab. I’m trying to run the "printf" example.

Everything works fine, but I do not get any output on the last line. How can I solve it?

```
import pycuda.driver as drv
import pycuda.autoinit
from pycuda.compiler import SourceModule

mod = SourceModule("""
#include <stdio.h>

  __global__ void myfirst_kernel()
  {
    printf("Hello,PyCUDA!!!");
  }
""")

function = mod.get_function("myfirst_kernel")
function(block=(4,4,1)) 

# Flush context printf buffer 
cuda.Context.synchronize()
```

Answer (score 1):

drv.Context.synchronize()

just make this change, it will work now.